# How to solve this during compiling WSO2API_Manager 1.5.0?

Tags: compilation, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We downloaded the latest source code of WSO2API_Manager 1.5.0.But during compilation of "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl"，it occurred an error:

method :getLength() can't be found in class org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.pagination.PaginationContext.

I searched this imformation through Google and founded this SVN record: 
http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/commits/2013-September/045568.html. it shows the error is fixed in Sep 30 ,2013.

But the jar I used is donwloaded from
http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.registry.core/4.2.0/ org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.The jar is updated Wed Sep 04 08:27:16 PDT 2013.It means the jar is expired.

So what should I do if I want to compile the source code? Download all the dependencies and compile them one by one , or just wait for the jar to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0001 and trigger a buid from patch001.

Then continue your build from the failed point.